# Solve the following system of equations:$|x|+|y|=2$ and $y=x+1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, systems-of-equations, absolute-value

> Solve the following system of equations:
>
> $|x|+|y|=2$ and $y=x+1$, where $x$ is a real number.

**Approach:**

I substituted $y$ in equation $1$, so:

$$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ |x|+|x+1|=2$$

$$1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1$$

$$2 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0$$

$$0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 2$$

These are the total possibilities I think, because $|x|, |x+1| \ge 0$.

Then I made cases,

**Case $1$:** $|x|=1$, so, $x = \pm 1$

and $|x+1| = 1$, so $x+1=\pm 1$ so, $x = 0,-2$.

But no value of $x$ is matching, so this case gets rejected.

**Case $2$:** $|x|=2$, so, $x = \pm 2$

and $|x+1| = 0$, so $x=-1$.

But no value of $x$ is matching, so this case also gets rejected.

**Case $3$:** $|x|=0$, so, $x = 0$

and $|x+1| = 2$, so $x+1 = \pm 2$ and so, $x=1,-3$.

Here also, no value of $x$ is matching. So no solution exists.

Is this solution correct? Please confirm. If there is a shorter method to approach the question, please share it.

Comment: Is $x\in\Bbb R$? In that case $x=\frac{1}{2}$ would also work

Comment: It is a lot easier to find the solutions graphically. Are you allowed to do that?

Comment: @DatBoi, yes graphical soln is allowed.

Comment: @DatBoi Yes, as intersections of a square (first equation) and a straight line (second equation).

Comment: @Patricio, yes, $x$ belongs to real numbers

Comment: @JeanMarie exactly!

Comment: When one makes cases in such an equation, the cases to be considered are $x>0$ or $x\le0, x+1>0$ or $x+1\le0$. The way you make cases, there can be really many many cases if large numbers are involved, instead of $1$ and $2$.

Comment: These cases can also be reduced if you apply a standard inequality for absolute values, see my answer.

Comment: Did you understand exactly how I got the system equations and did you realize that the second system of equation has no solution?

Comment: @lonestudent I did, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### HINT

- If $x≥0$, then $y=x+1>0$

$$\begin{cases} x+y=2 \\ y=x+1 \end{cases}$$

Then,  we need

- If $-1≤x<0, ~y≥0 $

$$\begin{cases} y-x=2 \\ y=x+1 \end{cases}$$

- If $x<-1, ~y<0$

$$\begin{cases} -x-y=2 \\ y=x+1 \end{cases}$$

Comment: Of course, for the second case, the solution doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Image courtesy $-$ Martund.

$|x|+|y|=2$ is square on graph paper (you will get it by making cases).

and $y=x+1$ is line.

This is the shortest (not only) method I know.

Comment: I suggest you to add [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0yh4.png) picture in your answer (as a smoother version of yours). I've made it using Microsoft Paint.

Comment: @Martund always feel free to edit my answers and questions and thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

We know that $$|x-y|\le|x|+|y|$$
where equality holds iff $x$ and $y$ are of opposite sign. In this case we know that equality doesn't hold, so $x$ and $y$ are of same sign, so the first equation becomes $|x+y|=2$ and second is $y-x=1$. Making cases for positive and negative sign in first equation, we get the required solutions:
$$\left(\frac12,\frac32\right)\quad\text{and}\quad\left(-\frac32,-\frac12\right)$$

Comment: thanks for your answer (I ran out of upvotes I'm sorry about that). Could you explain how we know $x$ and $y$ are of same sign...

Comment: @Crease, if they were of opposite sign equality would have held in the first equation. But we know that the LHS is $1$ and RHS is $2$ for that equation, so $x$ and $y$ are of the same sign.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

One nice way to think about it is to see |x-a| as the distance between x and a. Visually, it's pretty clear only x=-1.5 and x=0.5 are solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You only consider integers, hence you might left out non-integer solutions.

We have $$|x|+|x+1|=2$$

$$|x-0|+|x-(-1)|=2$$

So the solution for $x$ is when the sum of distance from $0$ and the distance from $-1$ is exactly $2$.

Clearly, the point can't be inside $[-1, 0]$.

If $x$ is positive, then we have $2x+1=2$, hence $x=\frac12$.

Similarly, if $x<-1$, by symmetry, $x=-1-\frac12=-\frac32$.